# How to handle CloudKit "Couldn't decode zone PCS data" error?

Tags: ios, iphone, cloudkit

I see the error every time when I try to fetchRecordZoneWithID

```
- (void)fetchRecordZoneWithID:(CKRecordZoneID *)zoneID completionHandler:(void (^)(CKRecordZone * _Nullable zone, NSError * _Nullable error))completionHandler;
```

It returns zone == nil, and error localized description says:
"Couldn't decode zone PCS data"

error.NSDebugDescription : "CKInternalErrorDomain: 5004"

Interesting observation that zone was created on iOS 11 and it works perfect without any errors in iOS 11 (simulator and device)
When I try to do the same thing (fetch zone) on iOS 10 - I get this error every time.

Does it mean that CloudKit zones created on iOS 11 are accessible only from iOS 11?
Or it is fixable somehow?
Didn't find any information about this issue.
It's critical issue because user may have iPhone on iOS 11 and iPad on 10 and it will not work together....

Thank you,
Alex

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find the reason?

Comment: @Dmitry unfortunately no, I’ve switched to Firebase